# Open Refine / Google Refine - edit cells in multiple columns

Tags: openrefine

Does anyone know of a way to edit cells in multiple columns in Open Refine using a single command/action?

I have a project with about 75 columns, and I need to apply the same actions to all the cells in each column.

For example, I need to:

```
Edit cells > Join multi-valued cells
```

On every column in the project. Hopefully I don't have to do this manually for every column one by one?

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to 'Transpose cells across columns into rows'.

Then you can make the edits from a column, and when you're done, 'Transpose cells in rows into columns.

Here's an article that shows you how to go about transposing columns.

- [Cleaning spending data with Open Refine](http://schoolofdata.org/handbook/recipes/cleaning-spending-data-open-refine/)